# Use "many-to-one" and "one-to-one" on the same tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring backend, and seems to be having some kind of brainfart.
This is what I want to achieve:

```java
@Entity
public class Organisation {
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    private String organisationName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User owner;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "organisation")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

So I want users to belong to one organisation, but I want one user to be the owner of that organisation. How should I tackle this?

Comment: what happens if you try this?

Comment: Currently it says that I need to create a Organisation to be able to create a user, due to "not null". So I need to create an organisation to be able to create an user, but also need to be able to create an user to be able to create an organisation.